# $("input[type=username]").val() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am creating an AJAX log in form for my website; however, I encountered something I believe to be a bug in jQuery.

Code Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Log In</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="errors"></div>
        <input type="username" placeholder="username">
        <input type="password" placeholder="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Log In">
    </body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
            $(".errors").load(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "?username=" + $("input[type=username]").val() + "&password=" + $("input[type=password]").val());
            return false;
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

I know for a fact that it is not a server-side issue.  The return value for `$("input[type=username]").val()` is `undefined`, while the return value of `$("input[type=password]").val()` is the value of the input.
Thank you all in advance! :)

Comment: Before declaring "bug", make sure your test case is valid first. The [HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) would have shown you your error.

Comment: People think that harvesting plugins from the web make them jQuery *ninjas*

Answer (score 11):

`username` is not a valid `type` attribute value. I'm guessing you wanted `text` instead, and that is what the browser will default to when it encounters an unrecognised type. Therefore, when your code runs, the `input` actually has a type of `text`, not `username`.

See the [specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html#attr-input-type) for the full list of valid `type` attribute values.

---

Side note - upgrading your version of jQuery to 1.3.2 or (preferably) above will solve this issue. I would move away from the ancient 1.2.6 you are currently using as soon as possible!

See a [working version (jQuery 1.7.2) here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/t8NEr/). Change the included version of jQuery down to 1.2.6 and it will log `undefined`, as you say in your question.

Comment: Ok, thank you. The CSS supported the username type.  Silly me.

Comment: @PatrickMurray - See my update. If you update jQuery to a newer version it will work as you expect. I would still strongly recommend that you don't use `username` as a `type` value though.

Answer (score 4):

`"username"` is not a valid `type`, it will be treated as `"text"`

Use `name="username"` and `$("input[name=username]")` instead

[Here's a list of valid types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input#attr-type)